# How to change empty string to a null using Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, traits, laravel-5.1

While using Laravel 5.1, I am trying to check every value before it is saved in the database using Eloquent ORM. My logic is, first trim the value, if the value is an empty string `""`, then to convert it to `null` instead of just an empty string.

I was advised to create a Trait which will override the setAttribute method for that.

So here is what I have done

I have a new folder "app\Traits" inside of a file called    `TrimScalarValues.php` which contains the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait TrimScalarValues
{
    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (is_scalar($value)) {
            $value = $this->emptyStringToNull(trim($value));
        }

        return $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
    }


    /**
     * return null value if the string is empty otherwise it returns what every the value is
     *
    */
    private function emptyStringToNull($string)
    {
        //trim every value
        $string = trim($string);

        if ($string === ''){
           return null;
        }

        return $string;
    }
}
```

Finally I have a `app\Models\Account.php` file which contains the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\industry;
use App\Traits\RecordSignature;
use App\Traits\TrimScalarValues;


class Account extends Model
{
    use RecordSignature, TrimScalarValues;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'accounts';

    protected $primaryKey = 'account_id';

    const CREATED_AT = 'created_on';

    const UPDATED_AT = 'modified_on';

    const REMOVED_AT = 'purged_on';


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = ['client_id','account_name', 'company_code', 'legal_name', 'created_by','modified_by','instrucations'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
    */
    //protected $hidden = ['account_id', 'remember_token'];


    protected $guarded = ['account_id'];

    /**
     * Get the industry record associated with the account.
    */
    public function industry()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(industry, industry::primaryKey);
    }

    public function pk(){

        return $this->primaryKey;
    }

}
```

But every time I update a value, I get a white page with no error or logs.

When I modify the `app\Models\Account.php` and change `use RecordSignature, TrimScalarValues;` to `use RecordSignature;` then I do not get a white page but obviously the values are not trimmed and converted to null.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call `$this->setAttribute()` in your trait. Instead you want to call the "original" `setAttribute` method by using `parent::`:

```
public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    if (is_scalar($value)) {
        $value = $this->emptyStringToNull(trim($value));
    }

    return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
}
```

---

Regarding the empty logs, have you checked the webserver log besides the one from the framework?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it by creating a middleware that filters empty input fields.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $input = $request->all();
    if ($input) {
        array_walk_recursive($input, function (&$item) {
            $item = trim($item);
            $item = ($item == "") ? null : $item;
        });
        $request->merge($input);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Don't forget to add your custom middleware to Http/Kernel.php

Found this at [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/globally-set-db-as-null-if-empty/replies/40153)

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna take a look at this package:
https://packagist.org/packages/iatstuti/laravel-nullable-fields

"This create a trait and allows you to easily flag attributes that should be set as null when being persisted to the database."

I know this post is old, and at that time this package maybe didn't exist yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can use mutator in you model.
For the field account_name mutator should looks like this:

```
public function setAccountNameAttribute($account_name)
{
    if(is_null($account_name))
    {
        $this->attributes['account_name'] = null;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->attributes['account_name'] = $account_name;
    }
}
```

And everytime when you will update or insert the record using Eloquent, account_name will be passed through this mutator.

Comment: but I don't want to do that for every field in my database. If i have many columns/tables "models" this could become instead. Additionally is_null('') will return false which means I accomplish nothing!